# Why does place.latLng return null?

Tags: android, kotlin, coordinates, google-places

Call on `place.latLng` which calls `getLatLng()` under the hood, on Place's object returns null and not the coordinates.

```
autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(object : 
PlaceSelectionListener {
        override fun onPlaceSelected(place: Place) {
            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "" + place.latLng.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show()
        }

        override fun onError(status: Status) {
            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "" + status.statusMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show()
        }

    })
```

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem, but `PlaceSelectionListener ` is deprecated: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/ui/PlaceSelectionListener

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I forgot to add `Place.Field.LAT_LNG` to the place fields array.

```
Before:
    var placeFields = listOf(
            Place.Field.ID,
            Place.Field.NAME,
            Place.Field.ADDRESS,
        )
After: 

    var placeFields = listOf(
            Place.Field.ID,
            Place.Field.NAME,
            Place.Field.ADDRESS,
            Place.Field.LAT_LNG
        )
```

When you specify the array:

```
autocompleteFragment.setPlaceFields(placeFields)
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your GPS is on and location runtime permission is granted.

Comment: I'm not asking for device location, I'm only trying to get the coordinates from a google places search result.

Answer (score 0):

make sure allow in setPlaceFields what do you want.for example i want latlang so i have added LAT_LNG. see below.

```
 autocompleteFragment.setPlaceFields(Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME,Place.Field.LAT_LNG));
```